# adding -vtag parameter without re encoding video in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Can I add the ffmpeg parameter `-vtag xvid` to an .avi video that was encoded using ffmpeg with the parameter `-vcodec mpeg4` without re encoding the entire video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c copy -vtag xvid output.avi
```